# jQuery Modal Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugin

This is my first attempt at a jQuery plugin, which is a simple modal window.  I'm keen for feedback of whether I've got the principle correct, the usability of the plugin and any improvements that could be made.

Here is a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bagiqaru/3).

**The plugin instructions:**

1. Add one or more elements that will launch a modal when clicked. Give these a class of modal-open.
2. Add elements to display in the modal window. These should go in a `</div>` with `class="overlay-message hide"`. and the `div` needs an `id`.
3. Add a data-target attribute to the modal-open element(s) made in 1. The value of this should be the same as the id of the overlay-message element made in 2.
4. Add links to jQuery, overlay.js and overlay.css
5. Call `$('.modal-open').modalise()`

**The JS code:**

```js
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.modalise = function( options ) {

    // Add and initialise the overlay background 
    $('body').append('<div class="overlay modal-close hide"></div>');
    $('.modal-close').on('click',function(){
        $('.overlay').toggleClass("hide");
        $('.overlay-message').addClass("hide");
        console.log('clicked'); 
    });

    // Options for the plugin
    var settings = $.extend({
        // Default options
        width: "700px",
        closeButton: true
    }, options );

    return this.each(function(index){
        // Dom elements
        var openButton = $(this),
            targetSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target');

        // Add and initiate close button
        if(settings.closeButton){
            $(targetSelector).prepend('<a href="#" class="modal-close btn">X</a>').find('.modal-close').on('click',function(){
                $('.overlay').addClass("hide");
                $('.overlay-message').addClass("hide"); 
            });
        }

        // Show the relevant modal window on clicking the open button
        openButton.on('click',function(){
            var targetSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target');
            $(targetSelector + ', .overlay').toggleClass("hide");
        });

    });

};

}( jQuery ));
```

**The CSS code:**

```css
.overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.overlay-message{
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 660px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
.modal-close.btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 5px;
    color: black;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.modal-open{
    cursor: pointer;
}   

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .overlay-message{
        width: auto;
        left: 5%;
        right: 5%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a lot of issues in the future I can recommend writing your plugin in `"use strict";` mode. 
Next improvement could be using variables at the beginning of your function to make it faster and cache values. For instance:

```
$.fn.modalise = function( options ) {
  "use strict";

  var root = $(".body"),
      overlay = $(".overlay"),
      overlayMessage = $(".overlay-message"));

   [...]
}(jQuery));
```

Because each time your plugin is called, JavaScript will search through the DOM for `$(".body")` and all other elements.

**Edit:**
And you allready cached `$(this)`, why don't you use it?

```
return this.each(function(index){
  // Dom elements
  var openButton = $(this),
      targetSelector = '#' + openButton.attr('data-target'),
      closeModal

  // Add and initiate close button
  if(settings.closeButton){
    $(targetSelector).prepend('<a href="#" class="modal-close btn">X</a>').find('.modal-close').on('click',function(){
      overlay.addClass("hide");
      overlayMessage.addClass("hide"); 
    });
  }
```

I guess there are some more improvements you could make. I'm just not an expert in writing own plugins :-)

Comment: I can not see how html structure.however, in my opinion, when you defined root, then all other module's objects should use root.find() to find, not $().

Comment: I missed that another element is overlay, however, overlay is should be only-one element for this module, so it may  cache to store it and use the cache variable cross the this module object, rather than search it all the time

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ive made some changes based on that.

Comment: You're welcome. Furthermore you could use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) on your plugin which will analyse your code and display potential issues.